# How can we further “gamify” pit traps?

Tags: dnd-5e, encounter-design, traps

In “old school” computer adventure games like LucasFilm Games’ *Secret of Monkey Island* and the Infocom series which included games like *Zork*, the adventures were peppered with objects that used in clever ways were used by players to solve puzzles later in the game.

The origin of this question is that we were inspired by a post on Puzzling StackExchange showing [how to cross a 10x10 hole using two nine foot boards](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/how-do-you-walk-across-a-10-x-10-hole-using-two-9-boards?newreg=51a1b50a2a67480f85b45a9da53ad344) and also the Angry GM’s ideas on making [“Traps [not] suck.”](http://theangrygm.com/traps-suck/) (Language Warning)

As a result, we are wondering what other objects, tools or even spell scrolls (Level 1-2) might be employable in clever or interesting ways to cross pit traps. Theoretically, one example might be PCs using Web from a spell scroll at the top of a 50 foot pit and then covering the web in blankets from an area nearby so the PCs could crawl across.

As opposed to general principles of making traps more engaging, as per
[How to make traps and puzzles more engaging?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96173/how-to-make-traps-and-puzzles-more-engaging/96174#96174), we are looking for specific examples from play of using placed objects or tools that PCs used and found interesting, puzzling, but ultimately rewarding related to crossing pit traps.

Comment: This site is best for specific problems you are having. This way specific answers can be considered for their quality as a solution. Your question appears like an idea generation question which is either off topic or too broad.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Could you help clarify why “How to make traps more engaging?” at https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96173/how-to-make-traps-and-puzzles-more-engaging is not too broad and not an idea generation question - but this one which asks more a more specific puzzle solutions specifically for pit traps - is too broad?

Comment: I would consider that question too broad as well. I'll start a close vote there. Maybe a mod will clarify if I'm mistaken about the policy.

Comment: This looks to me like a discussion-starter more appropriate [for a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) or for [chat], rather than something that can have a best or correct answer. It looks like a good discussion to have! But a forum can handle it, and our site cannot.

Comment: @dopplegreener what about the question Praxiteles linked to. Is that the same situation?

Comment: @doppelgreener Appreciate the useful, diplomatic yet encouraging aspects to your response

Comment: @DavidCoffron The way I see it, the linked question is describing a frequently-encountered problem many would recognise (which helps make it fairly well-defined in scope) and has a specific objective and direction for resolving it. This question involves less a problem or the solving of one, more exploration of possibilities -- and would also necessitate discussing what a trap being more gamified would actually mean in practice. There's nothing wrong with that, but our site isn't very well optimized to performing that exploration; discussion platforms are.

Comment: While I think that this is an important question, it's not very good for the "single question" format of Stack Exchange. It's a better question for a discussion platform like a Forum or Reddit, which are much more suited to having multiple questions and answers than SE.